# How to add or delete user of shared folder and set their permissions by c++...?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, permissions, shared-directory

How to add and delete user of the shared folder and set their permissions by C++?

I think getnamesecurityinfo() can come in handy but I can't understand how to use it.

Comment: [Please read How to Ask on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).